# Retrofit2 Set-Cookie not present in response

Tags: android, cookies, httpurlconnection, retrofit2, okhttp

My serve side is sending Set-Cookie on client response, but on Android Side i am not receiving anything related to Set-Cookie in header.
My networking stack on android is Retrofit 2.

Here my request code,

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        String hostName = "https://www.mysupercoolhost.com";
        CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                .add(hostName, "sha256/p1")
                .add(hostName, "sha256/p2")
                .add(hostName, "sha256/p3")
                .build();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
                .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
                .build();
        RequestBody rb = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), "{\"user\":\"test\"}");

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .method("POST", rb)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .url(hostName)
                .addHeader("param1", "value1")
                .addHeader("param2", "value2")
                .build();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    client.newCall(request).execute();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

**This same piece of code works in Simple Java application and i can see values dumped in Set-Cookie key, but it fails on Android.**

**Note that my java app is maven project with retrofit2 dependencies only.**

Cookie Received on desktop is something like

```
INFO: Set-Cookie: test_443=9182912.910219021.0000; path=/
Mar 03, 2017 11:53:08 AM okhttp3.internal.Platform log
INFO: Set-Cookie: cutypie=wandarabigstring; Path=/
Mar 03, 2017 11:53:08 AM okhttp3.internal.Platform log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working, i had to manually set dns using okhttpbuilder.
The reason my code was working on desktop because

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

had

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
:1             localhost 
x.x.x.x  mysupercoolhost.com
```

Where as my android device didn't had this information

So i had to write

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.dns(new Dns() {
            @Override
            public List<InetAddress> lookup(String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
                return return Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.singletonList(InetAddress.getByAddress("mysupercoolhost.com", domain_ip_in_bytes)));
            }

    });
```